# return inside an except python

Tags: python, exception

What is the problem when including a function inside an except?
In my case I have the following function:

```
def inventedfunction(list1):
    print "initial list %r" %list1

    SOMETHING THAT CREATES list2 based on list1

    try: 
        list2[1]
        print "inside try %r" %list2
        inventedfunction(list2) 
   except:
       print "inside except %r" %list2  
       return list2
```

After running inventedfunction(somelist) it seems everything is working:

```
initial list [3, 562, 7, 2, 7, 2, 3, 62, 6]
inside try [[3, 562], [2, 7], [2, 7], [3, 62], [6]]
initial list [[3, 562], [2, 7], [2, 7], [3, 62], [6]]
inside try [[2, 3, 7, 562], [2, 3, 7, 62], [6]]
initial list [[2, 3, 7, 562], [2, 3, 7, 62], [6]]
inside try [[2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 7, 62, 562], [6]]
initial list [[2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 7, 62, 562], [6]]
inside except [[2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 7, 7, 62, 562]]
```

But it is not returning anything. If I include return list2 outside the except it returns [[3, 562], [2, 7], [2, 7], [3, 62], [6]] but not [[2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 7, 7, 62, 562]] which is what I want.

Also if I change the code for this:

```
if len(list2)!=1:
    inventedfunction(list2) 
else:
    return list2
```

There is no return in the function.

Another simple example that also doesn't return anything:

```
def inventedfunction(list1):
    list2=list1[:-1]
    if len(list2)!=1:
        inventedfunction(list2) 
    else:
        return list2
```

Comment: inventedfunction() may call itself and so is recursive. What is supposed to be the terminating condition of its recursion and is that always on an exception?  Because it returns something only on an exception.

Comment: I was trying to end the recursion when there is only one sub-list in list2 and that's why I was including list2[1] inside the try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are recursively calling the function - `inventendfunction()` - but never returning the result you get from the recursive call, hence it does not return anything back , you would need to return the result returned by the recursive call as well -

```
try: 
    list2[1]
    print "inside try %r" %list2
    return inventedfunction(list2)
```

Also, it is bad to have a bare `except` , you should think about what exception can come when calling `inventedfunction()` and only except those exceptions.

---

Since in the comments you say -

> I guess my problem doesn't have to do with the function but understanding how recursion works.

Lets take a simple example of function `a()` that does recursion and is similar to yours -

```
>>> def a(i):
...     if i == 1:
...             return "Hello"
...     else:
...             a(i+1)
...
>>> print(a(0))
None
```

As you can see above simple example returned `0` , why? Lets take this step by step -

```
main -> a(0)
```

1. You call function `a(0)` , here `i` is 0 , so you go to else part , and call `a(1)` .

   ```
   main -> a(0) -> a(1)
   ```
2. Now, you are in `a` again, with `i` as `1` , now you go to `if` part, and this returns `"Hello"` .

   ```
   main -> a(0)         #Returned back to a(0)
   ```
3. Now after the return you do not directly return to `main()` where you called `a(0)` , no it returns to whereever the function `a(1)` was called, and that was from inside `a(0)` , so you return to `a(0)` , and the execution continues, but since `a(0)` does not return anything, you get the default return value in `main` , which is `None.

---

For your example again, you need to add `return inventedfunction(list2)` , for it to correctly return the results from recursive calls, otherwise the return value of the recursed calls are thrown away and not returned back. Example -

```
def inventedfunction(list1):
    list2=list1[:-1]
    if len(list2)!=1:
        return inventedfunction(list2) 
    else:
        return list2
```

Comment: I need every time to recall the function to edit list2 until it has only one sub-list. So how should I handle that in this case?

Comment: Do you want the flatten the list of lists to a single list?

Comment: Is just an example of sorting a list using recursion. For that I create a list2 that modifies each time the list by merging sub-lists. But finally when there are no more sub-lists I need to return that list2.

Comment: You would need to show us what your function exactly does .

Comment: I just added a simple example of another function with the same problem because I guess my problem doesn't have to do with the function but understanding how recursion works.

Comment: Add a simple example to explain why you are having issue

Comment: I mean't added an simple example , check the answer. Let me know if you still have issues.

Answer (score 2):

Your function *only* has a `return` in the `except` clause, so it doesn't return anything if there is no exception.  Perhaps you meant to do `return inventedfunction(list2)` inside the `try`.

Comment: I´m not sure but is seems there is an exception as you can see in the print  "inside except [[2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 7, 7, 62, 562]]"

Comment: @user2246905: There is an exception in a deeply nested call, but when it recurses up to the higher calls, those calls return nothing, because the deepest call swallows the exception and there is no exception in the higher calls.